Functions with derivatives growing at rate $r>0$
Fix a non-empty closed subset $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}$.
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be smooth and such that $\sup_{x\in \Omega}\,|\partial^k f(x)|\lesssim k^r$ for some $r\ge 0$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ (including $0$).
If $\Omega= \mathbb{R}$ then, from this nice MSE post, we know that if $r=0$ then $f$ is a multiple/translation of the $\sin$ function; i.e.\ $f = c\sin(\cdot +b)$ for some $c,b\in \mathbb{R}$.
Is there a characterization of such functions when $r>0$ for $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$?

More importantly, what if $\Omega =[0,1]$?

sorry I mean $s->k$ (I sometimes use "s" for "smoothness").  So I'm wondering what classes of functions are included when we fix a "polynomial-esque" growth rate for the maximal $k^{th}$ order of its derivatives.

What do you mean by $\lesssim k^r$?

most likely $\exists C>0$, $\forall k\ge 0$, the sup is $\le Ck^r$.

Exactly what I meant :)

Of course, we can also write $\le k^r$ instead of $\lesssim k^r$ and it's still the same question (since we can replace $f$ by $cf$).

I think the argument from the linked MSE post still works (without having checked all the fine details): if $|f^{(k)}|{\infty}\le k^N$, then $f$ is entire of exponential type $\le 1$. By Paley-Wiener, $\widehat{f}$ is supported by $[-1,1]$, and this should give $|f^{(k)}|{\infty}\le |f|_{\infty}$, so that there are no additional functions.

@ChristianRemling That's a fair point.  I also edited the post to ask about the case where we only max over a compact domain e.g. the interval.  Then polynomials are clearly included...

Eh, do you really want $k\in \mathbb{N}$ including $0$? Because this would require $|f(x)| \lesssim 0$ which means $f \equiv 0$. Presumably you want $0$ to be excluded.

For the bounded case on $[0,1]$ there's not much to say.
First, let $T(x)$ be the power series
$$ \sum \frac{a_k}{k!} x^k $$
with the sequence $a_k$ satisfying $|a_k| \leq C (1+k)^r$ for some $C > 0$. This implies that $T$ has an infinite radius of convergence and converges to a real analytic function on $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, we can compute
$$ T^{(\ell)}(x) = \sum \frac{a_{k+\ell}}{k!} x^k $$
We have that for $\ell > 0$
$$ |a_{k+\ell}| \leq C(1 + k + \ell)^r \leq C\ell^r (2+k)^r $$
so for $x\in [0,1]$ we find
$$ |T^{(\ell)}(x) | \leq C \left( \sum \frac{(2+k)^r}{k!} \right) \ell^r =: \tilde{C} \ell^r \tag{*}\label{eq:T:der:bn}$$
and so $T$ defines a function with the requisite property.
Going backwards, let $T(x)$ be the power series
$$ T(x) = \sum \frac{a_k}{k!} x^k, \qquad a_k = f^{(k)}(0) $$
Our hypothesis on $f$ implies that $|a_k| \leq C(1+k)^r$ for some $C$, and hence the previous paragraph can be used to show that $T$ converges to a real analytic function on $\mathbb{R}$ with \eqref{eq:T:der:bn} satisfied for every $\ell > 0$ and $x\in [0,1]$.
For any $m > 0$, the order $m$ Taylor remainder theorem states that
$$ \sup_{x\in [0,1]} |T(x) - f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{(m+1)!} \sup_{x\in [0,1]} | T^{(m+1)}(x) - f^{(m+1)}(x)| \leq \frac{(C + \tilde{C}) (m+1)^r}{(m+1)!} $$
and hence $T = f$ on $[0,1]$.
Conclusion
If $f$ is a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$, then $\sup_{x\in [0,1], k\in \mathbb{N}}k^{-r} |f^{(k)}(x)| < \infty$ if and only if $f|_{[0,1]}$ is the restriction of some real analytic function defined by a power series $\sum \frac{a_k}{k!} x^k$ with $\sup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} (1+k)^{-r} |a_k| < \infty$.
(Which is admittedly rather underwhelming.)
